# pandas split list like object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

Hi I have this column of data named `labels`:

```
    [{'id': 123456,
      'name': John,
      'age': 22,
      'pet': None,
      'gender': male,
      'result': [{'id': 'vEo0PIYPEE',
        'type': 'choices',
        'value': {'choices': ['Same Person']},
        'to_name': 'image',
        'from_name': 'person_evaluation'}]}]

    [{'id': 123457,
      'name': May,
      'age': 21,
      'pet': None,
      'gender': female,
      'result': [{'id': zTHYuKIOQ',
        'type': 'choices',
        'value': {'choices': ['Different Person']},
        'to_name': 'image',
        'from_name': 'person_evaluation'}]}]
......
```

Not sure what type is this, and I would like to break this down, to extract the value [Same Person], the outcome should be something like this:

```
0                      [Same Person]
1                      [Different Person]
....
```

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the limited data that you have provided, would this work?

```
df['labels_new'] = df['labels'].apply(lambda x: x[0].get('result')[0].get('value').get('choices'))
```

```
                                              labels          labels_new
0  [{'id': 123456, 'name': 'John', 'age': 22, 'pe...       [Same Person]
1  [{'id': 123457, 'name': 'May', 'age': 21, 'pet...  [Different Person]
```

You can use the following as well, but I find `dict.get()` to be more versatile (returning default values for example) and has better exception handling.

```
df['labels'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['result'][0]['value']['choices'])
```

---

You could consider using `pd.json_normalize` (read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)) but for the current state of your column that you have, its going to be a bit complex to extract the data with that, rather than simply using a `lambda function`

Comment: Ya it works.. May I have some explanations on this and what type is this column? I try .dtype it returns as object..

Comment: yea its an object as recognized by pandas. more specifically, its a complex nested list/dict data structure, which resembles a json. As per pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dtypes) ... `Columns with mixed types are stored with the object dtype`

Comment: you jsut have to access the elements inside the list, and then the dicts, in a sequence to get to the key that you want to pull values from., as i have done in my approach

Comment: feel free to mark the answer if it was helpful :) I have edited my previous comment to add more context for you.